# Android closes my game

Tags: android, performance, memory-management

I have a problem with my videogame in Android. It shuts down randomly without saying anything while I'm playing it for a while. Before, It didn't close but now somehow, is doing it.

After this, I optimized the code and got a great memory improvement but it keeps doing the same at the same frecuency, which makes me think that maybe is not a memory leak.

It is not an unhandled expcetion neither, because I have a try/catch capturing all the exceptions in my game loop.

So I was wondering what could trigger a force close in my Android videogame... what would you suggest?

- Maybe is because the device becomes very hot.
- Is it possible that in a long loop could decide to shut down because it is taking so long and without saying anything?

Those two are my main hipotesis right now. I don't have any clue what is going on.

Comment: Did you read what I wrote? I have a try/catch in my loop and if there is a bug, it captures it. It is not a bug as it doesn't shut downs in a better device.

Comment: "Those two are my main hipotesis right now. I don't have any clue what is going on." -Neither do we without seeing code and the logcat.

Comment: Probably out of memory.  Google for how to handle uncaught exceptions and OOM.  You will not catch this with a try block.